# Why Hamiltonian cycle decision problem in NP-complete?

Tags: polynomials, np-complete, hamiltonian-path, cayley-hamilton

I was reading the algorithm book of Neapollian and Naeempoor and it says Hamiltonian cycle decision problem is np complete and CNF can be reduced to it .I understand that why it is NP but i want to know why it is np-complete and how CNF is reducible to it?

Comment: The standard reference is M.R. Garey and D.S. Johnson, Computers and Intractability, a Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness, W.H. Freeman and Co., San Francisco, 1979. If you can find a copy of that, you'll probably find the answer, or a reference to a source for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hamiltonian cycle is one of [Karp's 21 NP-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems) proven NP-complete in the early 1970's.  The reduction chain was Satisfiability -> Clique -> Vertex Cover -> Directed Hamiltonian Circuit.  The landmark paper ["Reducibility Among Combinatorial Problems"](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~sgk/teaching/grad/handouts/karp.pdf) gives the details of the reductions.